# Lift state up between components in react

Tags: json, reactjs, lift

I have a problem with the communication between react components. I want to pass values between the components "ProductNameSave.js" to "readJson.js". The values from "ProductNameSave.js" came from the component "windowForm.js". Because of this strucutre ("windowForm.js" -> "ProductNameSave.js" -> "readJson.js"), I think "ProductNameSave.js" is the "source of thruth".
Here are the components.
"windowForm.js"

```
import React from 'react';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import UploadPicture from './UploadPicture.js';

export default class FormWindow extends React.Component{
    state ={
        U_Factor:'',
        Solar_Heat_Gain_Coefficient:'',
        Visible_Transmittance:''
    };

    change = e =>{
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    };

    onSubmit= e =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
        this.setState({
            U_Factor:'',
            Solar_Heat_Gain_Coefficient:'',
            Visible_Transmittance:''
        });
    };

    render(){
        return(
            <form className="productForm">
                <Input 
                    name="U_Factor"
                    placeholder="U-Factor" 
                    value={this.state.prodValue1} 
                    onChange={e => this.change(e)}
                />
                <br />
                <Input 
                    name="Solar_Heat_Gain_Coefficient"
                    placeholder="Solar Heat Gain Coefficient"
                    value={this.state.prodValue2} 
                    onChange={e => this.change(e)}
                />
                <br />
                <Input 
                    name="Visible_Transmittance"
                    placeholder="Visible Transmittance" 
                    value={this.state.prodValue3} 
                    onChange={e => this.change(e)}
                />
                <br />
                <UploadPicture/>
               <button onClick={e => this.onSubmit(e)}>Submit</button>
            </form>    
        )
    }
}
```

"ProductNameSave.js":

```
import React from 'react';
import FormWindow from './windowForm.js';


export default class ProductNameSave extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      field:'', 
      open: false
    };
  }

  state = {
    fields:{}
  };

  handleChance(fields){
    this.setState({fields})
  }

  onSubmit = (fields) => {
    this.setState({fields});
    console.log('App component got: ', fields);
  };

  render() {
    const fields = this.state.fields
    return (
      <div>
        <FormWindow  onSubmit ={fields => this.onSubmit(fields)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

"readJson.js":

```
import React from 'react';
import MyAppChild from './readJsonChild.js';
import data from '../../model/data/ProductData/Material.json';
import ProductNameSave from '../ProductList/ProductNameSave.js';

export default class MyApp extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {fields: ''};
  }

  handleChange(fields) {
    this.props.onValueChance({fields});
  }

  render() {
      const fields = this.props.fields;
      var json2 = data[0]      
      var arr = [];
      Object.keys(json2).forEach(function(key) {
        arr.push(json2[key]);
      });
    return 
      <ul>{arr.map(item => <MyAppChild key={item.Name} Name={item.Name} Roughness={item.Roughness} Thickness={item.Thickness} />)}</ul>;
      <ul><ProductNameSave onChance ={fields => this.handleChange(fields)}/></ul>;
  }
}
```

"readJson.js" gets it's values from a separate component. The aim is to pass the values from windowForm.js via ProductNameSave to readJson to overwright the values in reaJson with the new values from ProductNameSave.
If I run the code, I get the following error:
Error: MyApp.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this problem?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `<React.Fragment>` if you are using React version > 16. This avoids adding another  element in DOM just for grouping other JSX elements.

```
<React.Fragment>
    <ul>{arr.map(item => <MyAppChild key={item.Name} Name={item.Name} Roughness={item.Roughness} Thickness={item.Thickness} />)}</ul>;
    <ul><ProductNameSave onChance ={fields => this.handleChange(fields)}/></ul>;
</React.Fragment>
```

Reference: [ReacJS Doc for Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

There is also another short-hand provided by ReactJS which is not supported by other tools yet. The same can be read in above doc page.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in readJson.js. The way this component returning JSX is incorrect. In React 15 every component JSX elements must be enclosed either with div or span etc.

Check below updated code

```
import React from 'react';
import MyAppChild from './readJsonChild.js';
import data from '../../model/data/ProductData/Material.json';
import ProductNameSave from '../ProductList/ProductNameSave.js';

export default class MyApp extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {fields: ''};
  }

  handleChange(fields) {
    this.props.onValueChance({fields});
  }

  render(){
    const fields = this.props.fields;
      var json2 = data[0]      
      var arr = [];
      Object.keys(json2).forEach(function(key) {
        arr.push(json2[key]);
      });
    let children = [];
    arr.map((item, i) => {
        children.push(<MyAppChild key={item.Name} Name={item.Name} Roughness={item.Roughness} Thickness={item.Thickness} />);
    });
return(
    <div>
        <ul>
        {children}
        </ul>
        <ul><ProductNameSave onChance ={fields => this.handleChange(fields)}/></ul>
    </div>
    )
}
}
```

if your component returns single jsx element then they no need to be enclosed between div or span, if more than one jsx element then they has to be enclosed.

Comment: Hi Hemadri, your code works. But I can not confugure the values from the readJson.js file. But I want to chance the values, which I have in the json2 with the new values, which I get from the productNameSave.js file

Comment: I have given solution for following problem "Error: MyApp.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object". Now its a new issue, what do you mean by can't configure the values I am not getting that

Comment: You are right! Thank you very much! The new issue is, that I want to chance the values, which I have in the json2 with the new values, which I get from the productNameSave.js file

Comment: NP. You are saying you are getting values from productNameSave.js file. As I see the productNameSave.js calls(renders) FormWindow  onSubmit ={fields => this.onSubmit(fields)} alone and you are passing only handler function. So how come you get values from productNameSave.js?

Comment: ProductNameSave calls via onSubmit values from the windowForm.js file. Via the windowForm.js file, I enter the values in the front end. I followed the [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) manuel to pass the values from ProductNameSave.js to readJson.js. Within this manuel they chance state to props and they also use handelChance function. But it does not work for me. And I do not know why...

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to lift a state up from windowForm.js via ProductNameSave to readJson, this is an antipatern. Instead, you can do the following:

1. Define state in parent component (in your case this is probably readJson component) and also define a method that will change the state and will be passed to the child component (in your case windowForm.js). Once you define such a method and pass it into child component, you will be able to call this method inside child component and this method will change the state in the parent component.

OR

2. Use Redux and keep your data in global state. These data will be available in all your components.